# Pattern matching a non-exceptional value using try-catch expression

Tags: scala, error-handling, pattern-matching, try-catch

I have a question regarding the try catch block .Here is an example :

```
val num = try {
  110 / 12
} catch {
  case ex: NumberFormatException => 0
}

val num1 = try {
  110 / 13
} catch {
  case a: num1 > 10 => 10
  case b: num1 < 10 => 12
}
```

I know `num` works so why is `num1` not valid? All the examples and articles I've seen only do the `NumberFormatException` or `ArithmenticException`. And also are greater than and less than not valid operators in the case statement? Is it possible to treat the try catch block like an if else block using pattern matching?

Comment: `case x: T` means **match** if the value is of type `T` and name it as `x`. What type is `num1`, also the `> 10` is not valid syntax. Finally, what did you even tried to do? `catch` is for catching exceptions, but it seems you want to transform the value.

Comment: Is this java? I've never seen that syntax. Edit: Oh, it's scala. But why does it have a *java* tag?

Comment: 1) That's not valid Scala syntax. Perhaps you mean `case a if num1 > 10 => ...`? 2) You can't test the value of `num1` in the same code block that's trying to define the value of `num1`.

Comment: @jwvh `val x: Exception = try ??? catch { case _: x.type => ??? }` nothing wrong with recursive definitions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are attempting to write something like

```
try {
  110 / 13
} catch {
  case a if a > 10 => 10
  case b if b < 10 => 12
}
```

however this is not valid syntax because a try expression is of the [form](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#try-expressions)

```
try { b } catch h
```

where handler `h` must be a partial function of type

```
PartialFunction[Throwable, T]
```

so `a` in `case a if a > 10` must be `Throwable` however `Throwable` does not have `>` method defined on it.

---

Consider monadic error handling using [`Try`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Try.html) instead of try-catch expression. This would allow you to simply `map` over in the happy case. For example, consider

```
Try(110 / 13)
  .map(num => if (num > 10) 10 else 12)
  .getOrElse(someDefaultValue)
```

[Handling Error Without Exceptions](https://www.scala-exercises.org/fp_in_scala/handling_error_without_exceptions) has some interactive exercises to get you started with the concept.

Comment: The much I prefer to use **Try** or **Either** I guess we should focus on answering OP's original question. And leave this as a suggestion / note at the end.

Comment: This answers the question, except for the part about using "pattern matching anonymous function" to do it.

Comment: @som-snytt Is the part about `PartialFunction[Throwable, T]` not correct?

Comment: pardon, I just meant OP liked case syntax. you can copy my neatly aligned arrows. :)

Answer (score 1):

Supplementing the other answer, if you itch to have a tidy list of cases:

```
scala> import util._
import util._

scala> Try(1/0) match {
     | case Success(i) if i > 42            => 42
     | case ok @ Success(_)                 => ok
     | case Failure(_: ArithmeticException) => 27
     | }
res0: Int = 27
```